# Monomorphism in an abelian category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $A\stackrel{f}{\to}B \stackrel{g}{\to}C$ be a complex in an abelian category, I.e. $gf=0$.

It is easy to see that there exists morphism $im(f) \to ker(g).$

Could you have a proof for it being a monomorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the fact that

$$ im(f) \to ker(g) \to B$$

is the monomorphism

$$ im(f) \to B $$

In other words, $im(f) \to ker(g)$ isn't just a morphism of objects, but it is a morphism of subobjects of $B$.

This is, of course, rather trivial if you allow yourself to prove theorems in abelian categories by diagram chase, since $im(f) \subseteq ker(g) \subseteq B$.

Comment: I understood. Thank you.